# Побитовая операция "& 0x7FFFFFFF" нужна только для отрицательных чисел?

Tags: c#, коллекции, словари, хеширование, битовые-операции

При добавлении новой пары в коллекцию `Dictionary`, как известно, первым делом сначала вычисляется хэш ключа. Затем над этим хэшем происходит побитовая операция `& 0x7FFFFFFF`, это можно увидеть в [исходном коде](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,326) коллекции.

У меня вопрос, если я все правильно понял, то эта операции нужна **только** на тот случай, если хэш окажется отрицательным числом, так как наш `int` может хранить отрицательные значения тоже. А результатом этой операции становиться **другое** число, которое всегда положительное.

Если все так и есть, то вместо:

```
 int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
 int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
```

Можно было использовать такой код:

```
int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key);
if (hashCode < 0)
{
    hashCode = hashCode * -1;
}
int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
```

Верно?

Comment: За исключением времени выполнения

Comment: @avp, второй вариант с условием, намного быстрее будет выполняться?

Comment: Наоборот. Вариант с `&` на современном CPU скорее всего вообще не займет лишнего времени, вычисление пройдет в конвейере на фоне выборки  из кэша памяти следующих команд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Краткий ответ - нет. И на то есть две причины. Во первых, Ваш вариант значительно хуже в плане производительности - он содержит сравнение и умножение. Сравнение это плохая операция для процессора - она может привести к большой просадке производительности. Читайте [Предсказание переходов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2). Оптимизатор умный, может исправит, а может и нет.

Во вторых, Ваш вариант иногда не будет работать. Представьте себе число, которое состоит из 1 и нули. Это самое минимальное число, которое можно представить в данном формате. Если произвести с ним операцию *И*, оно просто превратится в ноль, который не является отрицательным числом. Но если его умножить на минус единицу... тут все становится интереснее.

Давайте рассмотрим на примере одного байта, так легче. Наше число это 10000000b == -128. Умножив на -1, получим 128. Но 128 это также 10000000...,которое вновь стает -128, так как не влазит в один байт. То есть, умножение минимального целого числа, представимого в данном "размере" на -1 дает его самого. А это явно не то, что нам нужно было.

Comment: А я бы вот так сделал - вообще без лишней операции (естественно, без проверки переполнений):
`int targetBucket = (int)((uint)comparer.GetHashCode(key) % buckets.Length);` Какие у такого варианта минусы?

Comment: Согласен касаемо производительности, но не понимаю почему не будет работать всегда. `hashCode = -128; hashCode = hashCode * -1;` Не понятно, каким образом там может появиться -128?

Comment: Думаю, Вам надо в Майкрософт идти работать:). По факту явное лучше неявного. А приведение типов иногда может быть странным.

Comment: @Qwerti, так делать нельзя, потому-что как мы знаем, `GetHashCode()` возвращает `int`, который может хранить значения больше чем `uint`. И если метод вернет значение больше чем может в себя вместить `uint`, то теряется точность.

Comment: @AdamShakhabov, количество значений int и uint одинаково. Просто сами значения отличаются - отрицательный диапазон int'а оказывается положительным для uint'а. Но поскольку мы берём остаток от деления на число корзин, которое точно принадлежит положительному диапазону int'а, преобразование остатка от деления в int будет без переполнения и получится нормальный положительный int.

Comment: @KoVadim, не знаю, кому ты отвечал. Если других комментаторов больше одного, то уведомление никому не приходит (кроме автора ответа, если не он комментатор). Если ответ был мне, то хотелось бы поподробнее.

Comment: @AdamShakhabov, легко: https://ideone.com/sVCTkq

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, какую-то чушь я сморозил про разницу между uint и int :) А касательное твоего варианта, что насчет той же производительности, эти два подряд идущих приведения не медленнее чем единичный `&`?

Comment: @AdamShakhabov, так приведения типа в ассемблере вообще не существует. 4 байта - они и в Африке 4 байта. Просто команда деления изменится [примерно так](http://sadda.ru/pages/assembler-masm32/div/div.htm).